# Datagrid combobox getting relativsource to working

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I'm using the WPF combobox for filtering the items but I decide to put it in my datagrid instead but i can't get it to work probably in their i can only get it to work when is outside of the datagrid.

I think the problem is because

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, or ElementName=win
```

isn't supported inside the datagrid so how do I getting it to work.

this is the error I get

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedParam; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='Krydsmålbox'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')

```
<DataGrid x:Name="hjuldata" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsTasks}}"
CanUserAddRows="False"  BorderBrush="#FF303030" Foreground="#FF00FB0B" Background="#FF303030" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="644" Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="257" Width="1250" >
 <DataGrid.Columns>
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Krydsmålet}">
 <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
      <ComboBox   x:Name="Krydsmålbox" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="12" 
                  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate2}" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectedValuePath="Krydsmålene"
                  SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                  AncestorType={x:Type Window}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Height="40" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionChanged="Krydsmålbox_SelectionChanged" Canvas.Left="813" Canvas.Top="96" Width="146"/>
 </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

data template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cmbTemplate2">
    <WrapPanel Margin="0 5 0 5" Height="30">
        <Image Width="10" Height="20" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Krydsmålene}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF00FB0B"/>
    </WrapPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

CS

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public string SelectedParam
{
    get { return _selectedParam; }
    set
    {
        _selectedParam = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedParam");
        if (_selectedParam == "Krydsmål") { BindData(); } else { hjuldata.ItemsSource = FilterKategori().Tables[0].DefaultView; ; }
    }
}

public DataSet DTbindkryds()
{
    Data = @"SELECT Krydsmålene FROM Data.Krydsmål";
    //SQL statement to fetch entries from Krydsmål
    DataSet dsdata = new DataSet();

    //Open SQL Connection
    using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
    {
        conn.Open();

        //Initialize command object
        using (conn = new SqlConnection(connStrings))
        using (cmd = new SqlCommand(Data, conn))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapters = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            //Fill the result set
            adapters.Fill(dsdata);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    return dsdata;
}

private void bindkrydsmål()
{
    Krydsmålbox.ItemsSource = DTbindkryds().Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you define a data template for the grid and define a data type so that you could bind the selected value directly to some property?

Comment: becuase i couldn't get datatemplate to work with the header property

Comment: It's possible. Search for wpf datagrid header template

Comment: i had tryed using   `<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                                    <DataTemplate>
<ComboBox
</DataTemplate>` then it says system.windows.datatemplate in my combobox and my combobox don't exists in the curren't context

Comment: Problem is with your `Binding`, your `Path` should point to `DataContext.SelectedParam`.

Comment: this still gives me the error  `SelectedValue = "{Binding DataContext.SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
      AncestorType={x:Type Window}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: What is the DataGrid hosted in?  A UserControl, a Window?  Is it inside of a template?

Comment: herre is how it is hosted window>grid>tabcontrol>canvas>datagrid

Comment: @ominidata can you create a small sample that reproduces the error?  E.g. the full class definition and XAML?  If we can reproduce the problem there's a much much higher chance of solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your real problem is very small and frequent with `WPF` developers. Change your `SelectedValue` binding like below:

```
    SelectedValue = "{Binding DataContext.SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                       AncestorType={x:Type Window}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

As you have not given the code how you are assigning the `DataContext` for `window`, it's a viable option to check for. If it's the same `window` class then binding should work without `DataContext.` but the assumption that `RelativeSource` binding is not supported inside the `datagrid` is wrong. `RelativeSource` will work as long as element is in `VisualTree` of control and your combo box is in visualtree of window. Right?

To save time on proving the fact, below is the demo (created by using maximum of your code reuse and using template in header of `DataGrid`).

***XAML:***

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DeviceState}">                
            <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" SelectedValuePath="DeviceState"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.Items}"
                                SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding DeviceState}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>                                    
            </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" Width="200"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

***Code Behind:***

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        Items = new List<Device>();
        Items.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device1",DeviceState = 1 });
        Items.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device2", DeviceState = 2 });
        Items.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device3", DeviceState = 3 });
        Items.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device4", DeviceState = 4 });
        Items.Add(new Device() { Name = "Device5", DeviceState = 5 });
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }

    public List<Device> Items { get; set; }

    private string _selectedParam = "1";
    public string SelectedParam
    {
        get { return _selectedParam; }
        set
        {
            _selectedParam = value; 
            UpdateProperty("SelectedParam");                
        }
    }
```

***Output:***

[image: Combobox in datagrid header]

As  you can see in output that is a `combobox` in header of `datagrid` has a selected item by default and that is reflected using `relativesource` binding as you can see in above `XAML`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a DataTemplate in the `Header` property, use it in the `HeaderTemplate` like so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Krydsmålbox" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="12" 
    Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate2}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectedValuePath="Krydsmålene"
    SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
    AncestorType={x:Type Window}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Height="40" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionChanged="Krydsmålbox_SelectionChanged" Canvas.Left="813" Canvas.Top="96" Width="146"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
```

Once you do so, both `ElementName` and `RelativeSource` should work.

If you want to be able to refer to the combobox by name in the code behind, you can use a `ContentPresenter` to present whatever kind of Header you want (I think the default HeaderTemplate is a TextBlock instead of a ContentPresenter):

```
<DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
<DataGridTextColumn.Header>
  <ComboBox x:Name="Krydsmålbox" Foreground="#FFEAEAEA" Background="#FF303030" FontSize="12" 
      Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTest2}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cmbTemplate2}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding}"  SelectedValuePath="Krydsmålene"
      SelectedValue = "{Binding SelectedParam, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
      AncestorType={x:Type Window}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" BorderBrush="#FF303030" Height="40" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionChanged="Krydsmålbox_SelectionChanged" Canvas.Left="813" Canvas.Top="96" Width="146"/>
</DataGridTextColumn.Header>
```

Comment: it tells me that Krydsmålbox doesn't exists in the curren't context

Comment: @ominidata are you trying to use the combo box from code behind?  If so, then yes it will no longer be accessible.

Comment: @ominidata I've added an example that would allow you to refer to it code behind (via ContentPresenter)

Comment: that solved it but i still got the error `Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedParam; DataItem=null; target element is 'ComboBox' (Name='Krydsmålbox'); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')`

Comment: @ominidata odd, I cannot reproduce your problem.  What framework version and what's the rest of the XAML for your dialog?

Comment: is 4.5 and i have update my question with it and with the cs

Comment: is System.Windows.Data Error: 4